# Customize work item in Azure DevOps to restrict specific dropdown/picklist options in work item

Tags: user-interface, azure-devops, drop-down-menu, settings, azure-boards

I need to change the dropdown/picklist in the work item to show only specific option in the field's process.
The default setup does not filter the dropdown options according to the answer to a previous question.

The layout setup for field dropdown is
Question 1

- Option A
- Option B
- Option C

Question 2

- Option A-W
- Option A-X
- Option C-Y
- Option C-Z

scenario 1
In Question 1, I select Option A.
In question 2, I expect only Options A-W and A-X to be displayed.

scenario 2
In Question 1, I select Option C.
In question 2, I expect only Options C-Y and C-Z to be displayed.

Comment: What research have you done? Have you read any of the Microsoft documentation on how to customise work item templates?